# How do I use Option::unwrap_or_default when it contains a reference?

Tags: rust

I have a `candle_series` of the type `Vec<Candle>` that gets the last element and I try to use `unwrap_or_default`:

```
self.candle_series.last().unwrap_or_default()
```

But then I get this error:

```
method not found in `std::option::Option<&market::Candle>
```

How can I get the behaviour of `unwrap_or_default` on the struct instead of the reference?

My current workaround is this but it seems incorrect. If it is correct, please let me know:

```
self.candle_series.last().unwrap_or(&Candle::default())
```

Comment: That's not that bad. Still shorter than any other workaround I can think of.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Comment: At which object do you expect to point the reference to, if there is no objects in the vector? A reference **must** always refer to an valid object.

Answer (score 4):

> How can I get the behaviour of `unwrap_or_default` on the struct instead of the reference?

You'd need to either copy or move the reference (e.g. use `Option::cloned`, assuming your structure is `Clone`) so that your option is an `Option<Candle>`, and `unwrap_or_default` can do its job.

> My current workaround is this but it seems incorrect.

Looks fine to me, though of course it might be shorter to use e.g. `Candle::new()` if you have such an initializer.